# Geopandas plotting by specifying column at plot time

Tags: python, list, plot, geospatial, geopandas

I am reading a geojson data from [here](https://opendata.vancouver.ca/explore/dataset/zoning-districts-and-labels/export/) into a GeoDataFrame named `gdf`.

I have also calculated the centroids of each polygon using `gdf['centroid'] = gdf.centroid`.

I can individually plot either the centroids or the polygons by setting the column as the geometry column using `gdf.set_geometry("<centroid | geometry>")`. So, the following code works:

```
gdf.plot()    #By default the geometry column is the column to plot
gdf = gdf.set_geometry("centroid")
gdf.plot()
```

However, when I try to run the following code:

```
gdf['geometry'].plot() #Geometry column has been set as centroid before
```

Or,

```
gdf = gdf.set_geometry("geometry")
gdf["centroid"].plot()
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-0330c435e2c9> in <module>
      1 gdf = gdf.set_geometry("centroid")
----> 2 ax = gdf['geometry'].plot()
      3 #gdf["centroid"].plot(ax=ax, color="black")

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    953                     data.columns = label_name
    954 
--> 955         return plot_backend.plot(data, kind=kind, **kwargs)
    956 
    957     __call__.__doc__ = __doc__

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\__init__.py in plot(data, kind, **kwargs)
     59             kwargs["ax"] = getattr(ax, "left_ax", ax)
     60     plot_obj = PLOT_CLASSES[kind](data, **kwargs)
---> 61     plot_obj.generate()
     62     plot_obj.draw()
     63     return plot_obj.result

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py in generate(self)
    276     def generate(self):
    277         self._args_adjust()
--> 278         self._compute_plot_data()
    279         self._setup_subplots()
    280         self._make_plot()

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py in _compute_plot_data(self)
    439         # no non-numeric frames or series allowed
    440         if is_empty:
--> 441             raise TypeError("no numeric data to plot")
    442 
    443         self.data = numeric_data.apply(self._convert_to_ndarray)

TypeError: no numeric data to plot
```

Even though I can set the column as the geometry and then do the plotting, plotting by specifying the particular column at plot time is needed to overlay multiple geometries.

--FULL CODE--

```
import geopandas
import geoplot

gdf = geopandas.read_file("<path to file>.geojson")
print(gdf.head())
print(gdf.crs)
gdf.plot(legend=True)

gdf['centroid'] = gdf.centroid
gdf = gdf.set_geometry("centroid")
gdf.plot() #Works
gdf['centroid'].plot() #Works
gdf['geometry'].plot() #Error is thrown here
type(gdf)
```

Comment: It looks that `gdf` is a `pandas.DataFrame` instead of `geopandas.GeoDataFrame`.

Comment: `type(gdf)` yields `geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame`

Comment: That is weird, this is not expected behaviour. Can you post the complete code from `read_file` to faulty `plot` so we can try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @martinfleis: I have posted the entire code. Just need to enter the path to your geojson.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it without the line `import geoplot`? It seems to be working fine for me.[image]

Comment: I tried without `geoplot`. Unfortunately, the behaviour does not change.

Comment: It could probably also be due to older version of geopandas. You can try installing the most recent version of geopandas along with its dependencies and try again.https://geopandas.org/getting_started/install.html

Comment: I ran `conda update geopandas` and it says I have all dependencies fulfilled. So, I am on the latest one.

Comment: what does `geopandas.__version__` shows? This is most likely an installation issue.